# How can I get form_ID field from table before inserting the options?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have 3 tables on database,

**FORM**

> ·form_id
>     ·active

**FORM_OPTIONS**

> ·form_id
>     ·option

**FORM_RESULTS**

> ·form_id
>     ·option_selected
>     ·IP

When Ι create a poll Ι need to associate the options created for the new form, but **Ι don't want** to insert first the form_id field on FORM table, after selecting the last form_id on FORM and inserting this id on form_id on FORM_OPTIONS table. When sending the form, I want the new form_id on FORM_OPTIONS to be the same as form_id on FORM in one step.

That is to say, should know which is the newly created form_id on FORM to insert the same in form_id on FORM_OPTIONS table.

I know this is possible in PHP, but I don't remember how.

Comment: What database do you use? In Oracle or MSSQL >= 2012 you can use a sequence, that you manually increase and use as ID.

Comment: I use MySQL 4.0.9. The idea is use PHP to do this. I remember that is one line.